# What default port does phpmyadmin use?

Tags: phpmyadmin, port, forwarding

I would like to port forward access using my router to my database. Normally I would use something like http://192.168.1.2:8080. When use phpmyadmin I enter http://192.168.1.2/phpmyadmin. Problem is my router doesn't accept the portion'/phpmyadmin' as it contains text.

I saw some documentation which states phpmyadmin uses 3306. I tried http://192.168.1.2:3306 without success.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin is actually just using a webserver ([apache2 or lighttpd](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html)) to run - as far as I know.

Therefore you can define a config file for your webserver - apache2 example:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.2:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/phpmyadmin"

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

    ErrorLog "/var/logs/phpmyadmin-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/logs/phpmyadmin-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`phpmyadmin` usually resides in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` when installed by `apt-get`